# How can I do this without starting any activity or fragment

Tags: java, android, android-transitions

How can I do this When User Click On the Next Button Activity Should not change only data should change for example if there is `TextView` then its data should change and so on.

##### I want output like This Gif

[image: image desc]

#### If you have any doubt please feel free to ask in the comments

---

> I think this is able to do with the help of animation.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you can do this. You will need to have a list of data which will hold the title and the images. Then you can do one of the following

1. On your button click, change the text of your `TextView` and set the image resource of your `ImageView` by fetching the next item of the list manually each time.
2. You can use a `ViewPager` and update the current page when you click on the button
3. You can use a `ViewFlipper` and manually add Views based on your data and change views on button click

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this view take on int counter with initial value 0 and use **[CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer)** method.

Create list which contains image and text values in model. on CountDownTimer method every tick you can increase the counter and set image and text again from the list index.

Comment: data should only change when the user click on the next button not every second

Comment: Do you need help with the animation part, or with simply setting the text and image resource?

Comment: @GavinWright if you do with animation it will be better other wise it will also good.